# Is there a way to remove unnecessary 'require(...)'/'import "..."' statements when using Rollup

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, bundler, rollupjs

I am creating a library, we'll call it `share` that will be used in other services and am bundling the library using Rollup.js

`share` is a shared library that is used by several services, so I need to be able to treeshake the library. What is going on is... let's say I have `service A` and `service B` that depend on `share`.

- `service A` uses `googleapis` which is one of the dependencies used by `shared`, however, `googleapis` is a peer dependency and is a true dependency of `service A`.
- `service B` does not use `googleapis` at all and is **not** a dependency. No functions are even included in `service B` from `shared` where `googleapis` is used.

---

When bundling, both `service A` and `service B` only include the functions/attributes that are required. The problem I am running into is on `service B`, when I look at the generated bundle, there is the following line...

`service A`'s generated bundle

```js
// ...
var path = require('path');
var googleapis = require('googleapis'); // works as expected
// ...
```

`service B`'s generated bundle

```js
// ...
var path = require('path');
require('googleapis'); // this line is causing my issue
// ...
```

Simply removing the `require('googleapis')` on `service B` does fix the problem as this library isn't used at all, even globally, however, this is just the beginning of this shared library, and I'd much rather not have to manually remove unnecessary requires, or write a utility to strip them out if there is a simple fix to this issue.

I figured there would be some setting that I could pass along to `treeshake`, but I have yet to find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out which property is responsible for this.

`treeshake.moduleSideEffects`

---

My solution was...

```js
...
treeshake: {
   moduleSideEffects: (id) => !id.includes('googleapis')
}
...
```

which I will need to include to prevent bundling an empty require statement